# SQL - grouping Multiple select sums

Tags: sql, select, sum

Can someone please advise on the following,

I would like to present two sets of data in separate columns - The total amount for each company.

Currently, the results are displayed in the same column and I cannot find a way to split them, does anyone have any recommendations on this?

[image]

I would like the data to be presented as

[image]

```html
Select Sum(Amount)
from ServerRoomStock
where CompanyName = 'B'
union all
Select Sum(Amount)
from ServerRoomStock
where CompanyName = 'A'
```

Comment: Please tag your post with the appropriate sql DBMS, such as sql-server, mysql, etc.

Comment: pivot function can achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT B.sum_company_b,A.sum_company_a
 FROM
( 
    Select Sum(Amount)   sum_company_b
   from ServerRoomStock 
   where CompanyName = 'B' 
)B
cross join 
(
  Select Sum(Amount) sum_company_a
  from ServerRoomStock 
  where CompanyName = 'A'
)A
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I get the following error message 

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'cross'.

Comment: please try amended

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `case` *expressions* to do *conditional aggregation*:

```
select sum(case when CompanyName = 'A' then Amount else 0 end) as sumA,
       sum(case when CompanyName = 'B' then Amount else 0 end) as sumB
from ServerRoomStock
where CompanyName in ('A', 'B')
```